# Are there good books retracing the history of (La)TeX?

Tags: books, tex-history

I am interested by books focused on the history of (La)TeX from philosophical point of view. That is to say: no textbook, no introduction to LaTeX for beginners but books describing the model of the software<sup>1</sup>, comparing this model to others, trying to analyze its evolution through time, the community, ...

Do you have any references (not only books; it could be websites or unpublished papers)?

---

<sub>1. I am not sure if we can call LaTeX a software. And this is the kind of debate I am interested to read about.</sub>

Comment: I am not aware of any book in this respect and I am not sure if there is enough "in it" to make it a book. To me, this sounds more like a good topic for a thesis in the humanities. So you might want want to try looking for BA/MA theses in this respect.

Comment: not exactly what you're looking for, but might provide some information:  a 2003 article by Alexandre Gaudeul in tugboat: [The (La)TeX project: A case study of open source software](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-1/gaudeul.pdf).  you might also look at the q&a sessions with Knuth in tugboat; see the [contents list by author](http://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listauthor.html#Knuth,Donald) for information about tex itself.

Comment: [A brief history of TEX, volume II by Arthur Reutenauer at TUGBoat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb29-1/tb91reutenauer.pdf) and its [video by river-valley](http://youtu.be/-p9aKUk_Sgg)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Books

That's a tall order and there aren't many books that would fit (and none perfectly that I know of). But here we go:

- Knuth: *Digital Typography*. Interesting set of papers by Don written about typesetting and his thoughts on it.

### Papers and talks

Probably some papers in old tugboats available from [tug.org](http://tug.org/), again it might be difficult to find them in the mass of technical papers.
There are several related papers in the [DocEng conferences](http://www.documentengineering.org/). But finding the right ones will probably be a challenge --- at least most of the older ones are available freely on the net [e.g. epodd papers](http://cajun.cs.nott.ac.uk/compsci/epo/papers/epoddtoc.html).

Some taped conference talks. You find links to them on [the LaTex project web site](http://latex-project.org/papers/), e.g. Here I mention two but perhaps there are a few others.

- Chris Rowley: *A brief history of LaTeX — with a prediction*: [video via River Valley TV](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/a-brief-history-of-latex%e2%80%94with-a-prediction/)
- Frank Mittelbach: *Windows of opportunity: A (biased) personal history
  of two decades of LaTeX development — Are there lessons to be
  learned?*: [link](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/two-decades-of-latex-development/)

Some papers of mine deal with some aspects of LaTeX history, see [downloadable papers](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Frank_Mittelbach/) at Research Gate. e.g., *LPPL history*, *Guidelines for future TeX extensions*, *The Pursuit of Quality* and perhaps a few others.

There was a paper on Leslie's birthday on history of LaTeX by Chris Rowley "The LaTeX Legacy", which gives some interesting insights, but to my knowledge this is unfortunately only available [at the ACM library](https://dl.acm.org/purchase.cfm?id=383978&CFID=269822374&CFTOKEN=99422582).

---

#### Some partially related papers

- Alexandre Gaudeul: *The (La)TeX project: A case study of open source software* (Barbara mentioned that already).
- The [TUG interviews](http://www.tug.org/interviews). Some of them are surely giving a lot of insight into the history and evolution of TeX/LaTeX et al but it will be difficult to distill. By the way, most of them are available as a neat (non-free) book directly from the [TUG website](http://www.tug.org/store/texpeople/).
- Rosemary Sasson: [*Computers and Typography*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1871516234) only marginally related but contains a lot of the thoughts that have influenced Don and others at the time.

Answer (score 13):

You may also want to look at [The Computer Science of TeX and LaTeX](http://www.eijkhout.net/texsci/index.html), by Victor Eijkhout. I'm not sure if it qualifies as a philosophical treatise -- actually, I'm pretty sure it doesn't! -- but it contains neat gems here and there on issues of design and implementation that go far beyond the usual style of intros to LaTeX (and TeX).

Answer (score 8):

I think that "Computers and Typesetting" by Donald Knuth would be crucial in spite of being a 5-volume-set of books by the TeX creator himself.

Alternatively, and far more easily digestible, I recommend a set of:

- [Lecture videos](http://www.webofstories.com/play/donald.knuth/51)
- [Interviews](http://www.tug.org/interviews/)

Answer (score 4):

In *Literate Programming* (D. Knuth) there are a few articles about the development of TeX which include a complete listing of all bugs found and an overview over the development phases. Your local university's library might have a copy.

Comment: Somewhere available via `texdoc` there is Knuth's development log for the project.  I saw it once upon a time, but it's lost to memory.  Perhaps someone knows where it is.

Comment: look in the Knuth folder.

Comment: Got it! [`texdoc errorlog`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/errata/errorlog.pdf) I didn't get your tip until know, @FUZxxl, but it would've led me there.

Comment: Yeah, one of the articles in Literate Programming is that log printed out.