# What is this file and how to compile and tranform it?

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

I was given some files to update. They were produced in late 1990s and seemed to be related to LaTeX. However, I could not compile them at all. To begin with, there is no `\begin{}` or `\end{}`. In addition, the table is very different from what I usually use. One example is listed below. My questions are as follows. Thank you!

1—What is this file, please? LaTeX or some earlier version?

2—How to compile it with TeXmaker, please?

3—Is there a quick way to convert this into the commonly used LaTeX file, please?

```
\magnification=1095
\baselineskip=14pt
\vfuzz=10pt
\hfuzz=5pt
\vsize=24truecm
\nopagenumbers
\font\bggf=cmr12 at 14pt
\font\bgf=cmr12
\font\bgff=cmbx12


\input psfig.sty


\headline={\ifnum\pageno>1
{\tenrm \hfill TITLE; \hfil Page \folio}
\else\hfil SUBJECT CODE\fi}

\centerline {\bggf UNIVERSITY}
\centerline {\bggf SCHOOL}
\medskip
\centerline {\bgff SUBJECT}
\centerline {\bgf (SUBJECT CODE)}
\centerline {\bf TITLE}

\bigskip

\item{1.} 

\medskip

\centerline{TABLE OF SOMETHING}
\smallskip
\moveright 1.0in \vbox{\hsize=4in
\settabs 5 \columns
\+&&&\hfil Values of $Y$ \hfil&\cr
\kern -6pt
\+\hfil Values \hfil&\cr
\kern -6pt
\+\hfil \ \ of $X$: \hfil&\vrule height 14pt depth 6pt&\hfil 0 \hfil&\hfil 1 \hfil&\hfil 2 \hfil&\cr
%\smallskip
\hrule
\smallskip
\kern -3pt
\+\hfil  \hfil&\vrule height 14pt&\hfil   \hfil&\hfil  \hfil&\hfil  \hfil&\cr
\+\hfil  \hfil&\vrule height 14pt&\hfil   \hfil&\hfil  \hfil&\hfil  \hfil&\cr
\+\hfil  \hfil&\vrule height 14pt depth 4pt&\hfil  \hfil&\hfil  \hfil&\hfil  \hfil&\cr
}

\itemitem{(a)} 
\itemitem{(b)} 
\itemitem{(c)} 
\itemitem{(d)} 
\itemitem{(e)} 
\itemitem{(f)} 

\medskip

\item{2.} 
\item{} 

\vfill\eject
\bye
```

Comment: You should compile it with TeX, not LaTeX.

Comment: It is a `.tex` file written in plain TeX. Compile it as `pdftex file` (file is the file name). Conversion.... Write it new in LaTeX.

Comment: @Werner What do you mean? How to do it anyway? Never used TeX before.

Comment: @HarishKumar There is no pdftex in texmaker at all. Where to find such thing, please?

Comment: @HarishKumar By the way, do you happen to know a good summary of the history on TeX and its later versions, please? I am very confused with all these things.

Comment: @LaTeXfan Go to Options > Confiigure TeXmaker > Quick Build tab. In that there is user: . In the field type `pdftex %.tex` and press OK. Then `Quick build` executes the command.

Comment: @LaTeXfan TeX is the base, LaTeX is a set of macros written in TeX and supposed to be more user friendly than TeX.

Comment: There is a question on the history of TeX/LaTeX [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148968/are-there-good-books-retracing-the-history-of-latex)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The text is written in the TeX format "plain". It's the very old format, provided by Knuth. Also the file loads package `psfig`. Neither TeX Live nor MiKTeX do not have this package anymore, thus it needs to be downloaded from CTAN, see this [link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfig). Since nowadays there are better packages for graphics inclusion, see package `graphicx` that can also be used in plain TeX with the help of `miniltx`, I would not bother to install `psfig`, but copy the file `psfig.sty` in the working directory alongside the old plain TeX files from your university.
Then the compile sequence (command line) would be:

```
tex oldtexfile.tex
dvips oldtexfile
ps2pdf oldtexfile
```

If the old TeX file does not need `psfig` as in the example of the question, then it can be removed or the line commented:

```
% \input psfig.sty
```

Then the example can directly compiled to PDF via `pdftex`:

```
pdftex oldtexfile.tex
```

IMHO the example of the question does not show much worth for preserving. Therefore, I would rewrite the file in LaTeX with better typography. For example, the table could be set with `booktabs` the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Table of something}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Values of $Y$} \\
      \cmidrule{2-4}
      Values of $X$ & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
      \midrule
      \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result for table]